# Creating thumbnail and resizing problems

Tags: php, php-gd

I'm trying to create thumbnail and resize image at the same time, so to be more clear here is the image that i'm trying to crop:

[image]

And i would like to cut out that red area.

Now my problem is that i'm resizing my image with html before croping so when i submit data to php i get incorrect values, like `y = 100` when realy it could be `y = 200` so i need to find a way to calculate my values.

I am using `imagecopyresampled`, maybe there is something better then this command?

Also my closest soliution was this:

```
imagecopyresampled(
    $thumb, //Destination image link resource.
    $src,   //Source image link resource.
    0,      //x-coordinate of destination point.
    0,      //y-coordinate of destination point.
    0,      //x-coordinate of source point.
    0,      //y-coordinate of source point.
    120,    //Destination width.
    160,    //Destination height.
    $image_width/2, //Source width.
    $image_height/2  //Source height.
);
```

In this case it would cut out left corner but size would be not the same as my red box.
So i guess i need to get `source width` and `source height` right and everything else should fit perfectly, anyways i hope i make any sense here :)

**EDIT** Sorry i forgot to mention, `$image_width` and `$image_height` is the original image size

**EDIT 2** To be more clear this is what i get when i resize with this code

```
$dimensions = getimagesize('testas.jpg');

$img = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 160); 
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg('testas.jpg');

imagecopyresampled($img, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, 120, 160, $dimensions[0]/2, $dimensions[1]/2); 

imagejpeg($img, 'test.jpg');
```

[image]

Resized image size is correct, but as you can it doesn't look right.

Comment: Which commands do you use to obtain incorrect values? If you use `getimagesize` after upload as BenM suggests, it should be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use something like this to scale images:

```
public static function scaleProportional($img_w,$img_h,$max=50)
{
    $w = 0;
    $h = 0;

    $img_w > $img_h ? $w = $img_w / $img_h : $w = 1;
    $img_h > $img_w ? $h = $img_h / $img_w : $h = 1;

    $ws = $w > $h ? $ws = ($w / $w) * $max : $ws = (1 / $h) * $max;
    $hs = $h > $w ? $hs = ($h / $h) * $max : $hs = (1 / $w) * $max;

    return array(
        'width'=>$ws,
        'height'=>$hs
    );
}
```

usage:

```
            $getScale = Common::scaleProportional($prevWidth,$prevHeight,$scaleArray[$i][1]);
            $targ_w = $getScale['width'];
            $targ_h = $getScale['height'];
            $jpeg_quality = 100;

            $src = $prevdest;

            $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
            $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );
            //imagecopyresampled(dest_img,src_img,dst_x,dst_y,src_x,src_y,dst_w,dst_h,src_w,src_h);
            imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,0,0,$targ_w,$targ_h,$prevWidth,$prevHeight);
            imagejpeg($dst_r, 'assets/images/'.$scaleArray[$i][0].'/'.$filename, $jpeg_quality);
            $complete[] = $scaleArray[$i][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'resizing with HTML', do you mean specifying the size using the `width` and `height` attributes of the `img` element? If so, this won't affect the dimensions of the file on the server, and you can still get those using `getimagesize`.

Something like this will return the source width and height of the image:

```
function get_source_size($the_file_path)
{
    $imagesize = getimagesize($the_file_path);
    return array('width' => $imagesize[0], 'height' => $imagesize[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So after some time i was able to do it with my friend help, this is the script i used, maybe some one will need it in the future :)

```
private function crop($user, $post){
    //get original image size
    $dimensions = getimagesize($post['image_src']);

    //get crop box dimensions
    $width = $post['w'] * ($dimensions[0] / $post['img_width']);
    $height = $post['h'] * ($dimensions[1] / $post['img_height']);

    //get crop box offset
    $y = $post['y'] * ($dimensions[1] / $post['img_height']);
    $x = $post['x'] * ($dimensions[0] / $post['img_width']);

    //create image 120x160
    $img = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 160); 
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($post['image_src']);

    imagecopyresampled($img, $src, 0, 0, $x, $y, 120, 160, $width, $height);

    //and save the image 
    return imagejpeg($img, 'uploads/avatars/'.$user->id.'/small/'.$post['image_name'].".jpg" , 100);
}
```